# How to do full copy from moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to copy `moment` to a new variable without references.

```
let momentDate  = moment('2018-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD');

// I need to create a full clone of moment here
// Tried: 
// -- let copy = {...moment}   
// -- let copy = new(moment)   
// -- let copy = clone(moment) // https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone
// -- let copy = Object.assign({}, moment)
let momentCopy  = /*new*/ moment; 

momentCopy.fn.xFormat = function() {
    return this.format('[new-format-fn::]' + 'YYYY-MM-DD')
}

// expected Error:momentDate.xFormat is not a function
// but xFormat applied to momentDate
log(momentDate.xFormat()); 

log(momentCopy().xFormat())
```

Can anyone help me?

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/hwj3vbq4/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `moment(Moment);` to [clone](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/) a moment object.

And `moment.fn` is moment prototype. If you want to add custom method to copied object, you can set as `momentCopy.xFormat = function(){}`

```js
let momentDate  = moment('2018-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD');

let momentCopy  = moment(momentDate); 

momentCopy.xFormat = function() {
    return this.format('[new-format-fn::]' + 'YYYY-MM-DD')
}
console.log(momentCopy.xFormat())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

From [the docs,](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/)

> All moments are mutable. If you want a clone of a moment, you can do so implicitly or explicitly. Calling `moment()` on a moment will clone it.

So just provide it back to `moment( momentObj )`

Answer (score 0):

Import "cloneDeep" from "Lodash" and then

```
let momentCopy  = cloneDeep(moment);
```

should work for you.

Comment: The result is `momentCopy  is not a function`. It works like `{...moment}` and returns an `Object` but moment is function.  However I cant add `lodash` to my project

Comment: Indeed lodash cloneDeep does not support Moment cloning properly and barfs. We had to customize the cloneDeep to support Moment...